# use onclick method twice

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to do something in Javascript when I click on a button, but onclick I want to scroll to a specific place.

I can do it if I use `<a></a>` like this

```
<a href="#cell">click</a>
<a name="cell"></a>
```

but I want to do that when using a button like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="doSomthing()" />
```

I want, when clicking that button, to do the same thing like in the `<a>` example I gave above.

Comment: If someone makes JS Scream Ill upvote it to oblivion.

Comment: @Loktar can I use activeX to call the m/b beep?

Comment: You mean JS doesn't scream all the time? What have I been hearing then?

Comment: i mean if u tried the first code u will take the scream to the "cell" , but i want to slide the scream to the cell using button not <a> tag

Comment: Ahh, finally.  Not scream, but screen, with an "n".  And some other letters.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan that might take a ventriloquist plugin or something along those lines to slide the scream around.

Comment: [Scream](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_jUC4wFJIC9w/ShJXbRwy75I/AAAAAAAACuk/UlHdtHf7HMU/s400/scream.gif), [Screen](http://www.altair680kit.com/images/070707-Basic_Demo_CRT_2789.jpg)

Comment: sorry , i am bad in english :)

Comment: Not sure why the down-votes, it seemed like a fair question. It even had a sense of humor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
location = "#cell";
```

Comment: Put that in your JS code and it'll scream erm scroll to the given location.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: I mean that you need to add a line of Javascript code.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan `function doSomething() { window.location = "#cell"; }`

Comment: You probably forgot to suppress the form submission.